# How to acces Linux HDD from VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I use Ubuntu Studio 20.04.2 LTS inside a 64 bit machine.

I also use VirtualBox 6.1 which I used to create a Windows XP SP3 virtual machine.

But, when I get in that virtual machine (WinXP), I cannot to read or write any from the Ubuntu mounted HDD partitions. I'm specially concern about the My documents folder (music, images, videos, etc.), because the WinXP virtual machine doesn't see that folder or HDD.

What I did wrong?

How can I get to read and write into the Ubuntu My documents folder when I am into the WinXP virtual machine?

Comment: Besides for Shared Folders, go to Machine/Settings/General/Advanced and enable Bidirectional Clipboard and Drag'n'Drop. This is more helpful than Shared Folders for quickly sharing data between Host and Guest.

Comment: Start your VM and then do "insert guest additions CD" from the menu. Run the installer. This is required for copy and paste operations, file dragging and all that.

Comment: I will try both solutions. Thanks!!!

Comment: @C.S.Cameron. I tried the "copy/paste" way, after to set to "Bidirectional". But, when I select some folder and/or file from Ubuntu and I go to WinXP (virtual machine), I don't have any "Paste" option inside the WinXP File Manager. What did I miss to do?

Comment: Did you install guest additions? Are you able to copy paste files from desktop to desktop?

Comment: I installed "guest additions" when I installed VirtualBox. I installed VirtualBox from the Synaptic Package Manager. I cannot to copy from the Ubuntu desktop to the WinXP desktop, or in reverse.